# Marketplace Gift Cards

Tags: magento-1.9

We have a Magento site that operates as a marketplace, as in there are many stores and sellers to browse through. I can only find extensions for gift cards that would work as products and be available to buy only through a specific seller. What I'm looking for is a standalone type of gift card (think Amazon) that would work across the entire domain/marketplace/website, not just specific sellers. Does this make sense to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is a non-typical use-case. Your best bet is to contact one of the companies that makes a gift card extension and see how much it would be for them to customize their extension for you. It should not be very expensive.